# SAS - Convert numeric values to character including dates

Tags: sas

I have a need to combine two sas datasets having the same column names but one of the datasets will have a numeric value where the same name in the other dataset are character.  I was thinking to evaluate each field with the `%isnum` function and based on this convert the number to character:

```
char_id = put(id, 7.) ; 
drop id ; 
rename char_id=id ;
```

What I need to know is how do I determine the length of the variable to use in the `PUT` and what would I do for date fields?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to analyze your data and see how long things are.  Use an obviously too long format (`best32.`) and then see how long the actual results are, or use `max`.

For date fields, you need to decide how you want your date fields to look.

```
date_c = put(date_n,date9.);
```

That would be the default, but there are literally hundreds of date formats you can choose from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `proc contents data=myDataStes out=VarDatasets; run;` and you will get the list of variables with type, length, format, informat and so on.